# Confused about residue of a complex, rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, rational-functions

I am asked to find $\text{Res}(i)$ for $R(z)=\frac{2z+3}{(z-i)(z^2+1)}$. Noticeably, $R(z)=\frac{2z+3}{(z-i)^2(z+i)}$.

While I understand how to find the corresponding partial fraction decomposition for the above equation, I am confused about the nature of $\text{Res}(i)$. Should $\text{Res}(i)$ be the coefficient for the $\frac{A}{(z-i)^2}$ term? Or the coefficient for the $\frac{B}{(z-i)}$ term? Or somehow both?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The [residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)) of $R(z)$ at $z=z_0$ is defined as $c_{-1}$ in the [Laurent expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) $R(z) = \ldots +\frac{c_{-1}}{(z-z_0)} + c_0 + c_1(z-z_0) + \ldots$. Thus in your case it's "$B$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z=i$ is a double pole of $R(z)=\frac{2z+3}{(z-i)^2(z+i)}$, hence
$$\text{Res}\left(R(z),z=i\right) = \lim_{z\to i}\frac{d}{dz}\left((z-i)^2 R(z)\right)=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{2z+3}{z+i}\right) $$
and
$$\text{Res}\left(R(z),z=i\right) =\lim_{z\to i}\frac{2i-3}{(z+i)^2}=\color{red}{\frac{3-2i}{4}}.$$
We have
$$ R(z) = \frac{A}{(z-i)^2}+\frac{\color{red}{B}}{z-i}+\frac{C}{z+i}+Q(z) $$
where $Q(z)$ is an entire function and the wanted residue is $B$.